# if-else VS map lookup

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

```
std::string v = GetV();
if(v == "AAA") {
    func1();
} else if (v == "BBB" || v == "CCC" || v == "EEE") {
    func2();
} else {
    func3();
}
```

Basically I want to do the conditional process just like the codes above. Since there might be more possible v value in the future, I don't think if-else statement is good enough. So I replace it with `map`;

```
enum v_type {
     v_type1,
     v_type2,
     v_type3,
     v_type4
};

string v = GetV();
const static std::map < string, v_type > v_map({
  "AAA",
  v_type1
}, {
  "BBB",
  v_type2
}, {
  "CCC",
  v_type2
});
auto iter = v_map.find(v);
if (iter == v_map.end()) return;
switch
case (iter->second) {
  case v_type1:
    func1();
    break;
  case v_type2:
    func2();
    break;
}
```

I think the map(Olog(N)) or even unordered_map would be faster than just string compare in if-else statement, but the trade-off might be the map itself both for memory and CPU. Am I right? Is it a better implementation with map/unorder_map than if-else?

Comment: If you combine that with the switch case as in your example, you most likely won't gain too much. Why wouldn't you store function pointers in the map?

Comment: Why not a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>`? Then you could put both the "keys" and the actual function to call in the map. There's three ways to figure out of a key is in the map ([`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count), [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) and with C++20 [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains)), and if it does just "call" the function directly from the map (i.e. `v_map[v]()` or if you use `find` then `iter->second()`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As speaking of performance I think only `find` really is a good option as the other two would impose double lookup...

Comment: Of how many strings are we talking at all? You might not really notice the difference until exceeding several dozens or a few hundreds of strings. In any case, you might want to profile your programme first, maybe the bottleneck is at a totally different place...

Comment: Consider your finite family of labels being used, derive a perfect hash function for those strings, then use that as the hasher for an unordered map of string to `std::function` as SPD describes, using `find` , then the resulting non-end iterator.

Comment: @Aconcagua Total number of  possible v value is about 15.

Comment: With *only* 15 strings we're still at a range where I'd prefer having most readable code above having highly optimised code (unless you call that `if` hundreds of times one after another). Which one would you consider more readable???

Comment: If you have some hints about which strings will be used more frequently and which ones less, then sort the former ones in front of the latter ones. That will improve performance as well.

Comment: As Aconcagua states: don't micro-optimize for no reason. It's a big pitfall of software engineers to optimize code where it's not necessary. If it's not a performance bottleneck, don't fix it. And if there's a performance issue with your code, Forrest determine where that occurs, instead of optimizing things that you think are the issue. There are good tools to profile cpu and memory use of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>>`, that maps a string to your functions. 
Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

void func1() {std::cout << "Func1" << std::endl;}
void func2() {std::cout << "Func2" << std::endl;}
void func3() {std::cout << "Func3" << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> myMap;

    myMap["AAA"] = std::function<void()>(&func1);
    myMap["BBB"] = std::function<void()>(&func2);
    myMap["CCC"] = std::function<void()>(&func2);
    myMap["EEE"] = std::function<void()>(&func2);

    std::string v = GetV();

    if (myMap.find(v) != myMap.end()) {
        myMap.find(v)->second();
    } else {
        func3();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You just have to define which string corresponds to which function, but then no need to use a `switch/case`.

Comment: Mapping to  function pointer is much better than my enum-switch-case implementation.